# PhpMyAdmin MySql fatal javascript error when creating table

Tags: phpmyadmin

Here is my reported error after trying to add a new table to my database. Have tried multiple coalitions and databases. I am inserting directly from phpmyadmin to do some initial testing.

Unsure what, "Object is not a function" is referring to, web has not been much help.

```
{
"pma_version": "4.4.12",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "44.0.2403.125",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "enabled",
"php_version": "5.6.11",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "object is not a function",
    "stack": [
        {
            "func": "Object.PMA_checkReservedWordColumns.$.ajax.success",
            "line": 2222,
            "column": "44",
            "context": [
                "        type: 'POST',",
                "        url: \"tbl_structure.php\",",
                "        data: $form.serialize() + '&reserved_word_check=1',",
                "        success: function (data) {",
                "            if (typeof data.success != 'undefined' && data.success === true) {",
                "                is_confirmed = confirm(data.message);",
                "            }",
                "        },",
                "        async:false",
                "    });",
                "    return is_confirmed;"
            ],
            "filename": "functions.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "j",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "27244",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.k.fireWith [as resolveWith]",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "28057",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "x",
            "line": 4,
            "column": "21843",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*",
                " * Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "b",
            "line": 4,
            "column": "25897",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*",
                " * Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.send",
            "line": 4,
            "column": "26001",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*",
                " * Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Function.m.extend.ajax",
            "line": 4,
            "column": "21302",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*",
                " * Copyright (c) 2013 Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "PMA_checkReservedWordColumns",
            "line": 2216,
            "column": "7",
            "context": [
                " * @returns true|false",
                " */",
                "",
                "function PMA_checkReservedWordColumns($form) {",
                "    var is_confirmed = true;",
                "    $.ajax({",
                "        type: 'POST',",
                "        url: \"tbl_structure.php\",",
                "        data: $form.serialize() + '&reserved_word_check=1',",
                "        success: function (data) {",
                "            if (typeof data.success != 'undefined' && data.success === true) {"
            ],
            "filename": "functions.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "new_func",
            "line": 279,
            "column": "33",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>",
            "line": 2646,
            "column": "17",
            "context": [
                "         * is actually an array of DOM elements)",
                "         */",
                "",
                "        if (checkTableEditForm($form[0], $form.find('input[name=orig_num_fi//...",
                "            PMA_prepareForAjaxRequest($form);",
                "            if (PMA_checkReservedWordColumns($form)) {",
                "                PMA_ajaxShowMessage(PMA_messages.strProcessingRequest);",
                "                //User wants to submit the form",
                "                $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize() + \"&do_save_//...",
                "                    if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data.success === true) {",
                "                        $('#properties_message')"
            ],
            "filename": "functions.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36",
    "uri": "tbl_create.php?target="
},
"script_name": "tbl_create.php",
"microhistory": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "hash": "tbl_addfield.php?db=nexter&table=test&server=1&target=&token=5a28badfae6602574cc0a6bc0fb21448",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "show_databases_navigation_as_tree": "true",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab2": "false",
                "LimitChars": "50",
                "pftext": "P",
                "confirm": "true",
                "LoginCookieValidity": "1440",
                "logged_in": "true",
                "auth_type": "config"
            }
        },
        {
            "hash": "tbl_create.php?db=nexter&table=&server=1&target=&token=5a28badfae6602574cc0a6bc0fb21448",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "show_databases_navigation_as_tree": "true",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab2": "false",
                "LimitChars": "50",
                "pftext": "P",
                "confirm": "true",
                "LoginCookieValidity": "1440",
                "logged_in": "true",
                "auth_type": "config"
            }
        },
        {
            "hash": "db_structure.php?db=nexter_primary&table=&server=1&target=&token=5a28badfae6602574cc0a6bc0fb21448",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "show_databases_navigation_as_tree": "true",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab2": "false",
                "LimitChars": "50",
                "pftext": "P",
                "confirm": "true",
                "LoginCookieValidity": "1440",
                "logged_in": "true",
                "auth_type": "config"
            }
        },
        {
            "hash": "tbl_create.php?db=nexter_primary&table=primary&server=1&target=&token=5a28badfae6602574cc0a6bc0fb21448",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "show_databases_navigation_as_tree": "true",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab2": "false",
                "LimitChars": "50",
                "pftext": "P",
                "confirm": "true",
                "LoginCookieValidity": "1440",
                "logged_in": "true",
                "auth_type": "config"
            }
        }
    ],
    "current_index": "4"
}
```

}

[image: Fatal Error]
Wish I could say more but I do not know why or how this is happening. Have played around with different methods and have searched the internet for an hour or 2 with to no avail!

Also which collation should I use? I know utf8 is standard but Im not sure which I should use. I live in the US just encase that is relevant. Also I am using xammpo for local development.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have tried plenty of different non reserved names. Thanks though.

Comment: May be try with a `SQL` statement : 
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`test_table\` (
  \`id\` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  \`test_column_1\` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;`

Comment: Hmm yes. Your syntax worked. It seems the gui is providing syntactically incorrect querys. Guessing my collation is messed up?? I am not sure but will keep trying to understand the core problem. Thanks though Uours!

Comment: I can think of two options : You could try [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) . Or you could set up another [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) .

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version is this?

Comment: 4.4.12 Converting to knew 4.4.13.1 soon.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: It was the installed version of phpmyadmin causing the problem. I just started using third party software to do manual inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out, clearing your browser cache and all related cookies (which start with `pma`), and logging in again.

Which collation to use depends on what data you're storing. utf8 is probably a good way to go if you're not sure.